# Why do LDMOS RF power transistors have a low real resistance?

Tags: transistors, rf, impedance-matching, input-impedance

I've been looking through datasheets for RF LDMOS amplifiers for use in an RF power amplifier. They typically have an input impedance that has some small real part of the resistance (<10 Ω) with a larger reactive component.

I can understand the reactive component being large due to bond wires or capacitive effects that would dominate due to the structure of the transistor silicon itself, but I'm confused about why we have such a low real part of the resistance.

LDMOS transistors seem to have their gates completely isolated from anything that could provide a low-resistance path to ground. Where does this low-resistance part of the input impedance of the resistor come from?

I think I'm either not understanding how the input impedance is measured correctly or not understanding the structure of the LDMOS internally correctly. The other potential explanation I could come up with is that this isn't the traditional ohmic losses that you might associate with a resistor, but more along the lines of dielectric loss that occur when you get an imaginary part to the effective dielectric constant.

Comment: Consider the definition of impedance, Z = R + jX.  What is the equivalent circuit of a small resistance plus a large reactance? What does this tell you about the Q (quality factor) of the impedance? And, given the design of an LDMOS transistor, what does that suggest about the bandwidth and gain available from it?

Comment: Ah okay. So there isn't a direct path that's resistive for DC as expected, but the reactive impedance is in series with a resistance which could be the bond wires/die traces. This suggests a lowish Q factor because the reactance to resistance ratio is somewhat low (depending on what you consider low). This also suggests a medoum bandwidth because the resistive component damps down the resonance response of the capacitance/reactance. Does that all seem correct?

Comment: Well, depending on sign, reactance may be positive (inductive, bond wires etc.) or negative (gate capacitance). The fact that Q > 1 suggests good efficiency (low input power), at least around whatever center frequency it was measured, and that the cutoff frequency is probably higher than this frequency. And mind this is at a particular frequency; it says nothing about others, or DC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> They typically have an input impedance that has some small real part of the resistance (<10 ohms) with a larger reactive component.

An ideal capacitor/inductor has *zero* real resistance. So it's all as expected! The input impedance has a fairly low ESR that's related to ohmic/bulk resistances.